# Integrating matlab graphs to tkinter (showing graphs on different pages) with csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, tkinter

I am new to Python and currently struggling to integrate the graph outputs that I have to tkinter. I am also getting an error whenever I try to run this. However, whenever I try to run the chinese postman problem code alone, it runs fine.

I want to put the graphs plotted form the chinese postman problem (instead of having it open from the default in Python) into tkinter but I am unsure how to integrate the two

Here is what I currently have so far, I am unsure as to what would be relevant and have inserted the whole code I have written so far:

```
    import matplotlib
    matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
    import numpy as np
    from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
    from matplotlib.figure import Figure
    from tkinter import *
    import itertools
    import copy
    import networkx as nx
    import pandas as pd
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import sys 

    class mclass:
    def __init__(self,  window):
        self.window = window
        self.box = Entry(window)
        self.button = Button (window, text="check", command=self.plot)
        self.box.pack ()
        self.button.pack()

    def plot (self):
    df1 = pd.read_csv("U:\\user\nodes_fixed.csv")


    #print(df1.isnull().values.any())

    df2 = pd.read_csv(r"U:\\user\edge_list_3_fixed.csv")
    print (df2)
    g=nx.Graph()
    # Add edges and edge attributes
    for i, elrow in df2.iterrows():
    # g.add_edge(elrow[0], elrow[1], attr_dict=elrow[2:].to_dict()) 
    g.add_edge(elrow[0], elrow[1], **elrow[2:].to_dict())


    # Edge list example
    print(elrow[0]) # node1
    print(elrow[1]) # node2
    print(elrow[2:].to_dict()) # edge attribute dict


    # Add node attributes
    for i, nlrow in df1.iterrows():
    # g.node[nlrow['id']] = nlrow[1:].to_dict()  
    nx.set_node_attributes(g, {nlrow['ID']:  nlrow[1:].to_dict()}) 

    # Node list example
    print(nlrow)

    # Preview first 5 edges

    list(g.edges(data=True))[0:5] 

    # Preview first 10 nodes

    list(g.nodes(data=True))[0:10] 

    print('# of edges: {}'.format(g.number_of_edges()))
    print('# of nodes: {}'.format(g.number_of_nodes()))

    # Define node positions data structure (dict) for plotting
    for node in g.nodes(data=True):
    print(node)
    print("")
    node_positions = {node[0]: (node[1]['X'], -node[1]['Y']) for node in 
    g.nodes(data=True)}

    # Preview of node_positions
    dict(list(node_positions.items())[0:5])

    # Define data structure (list) of edge colors for plotting

    # edge_colors = [e[2]['color'] for e in g.edges(data=True)]  
    edge_colors = [e[2]['color'] for e in list(g.edges(data=True))]

    # Preview first 10
    edge_colors[0:10]
    plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
    nx.draw(g, pos=node_positions, edge_color=edge_colors, node_size=10, 
    node_color='black')
    plt.title('Graph Representation of repair trail', size=15)



    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=self.window)
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
    canvas.draw()

     window= Tk()
     start= mclass (window)
     window.mainloop()
```

This was the error I got:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>        File "C:/Users/212749017/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37- 
>        32/testagain22.py", line 32, in 
>        for i, elrow in df2.iterrows():
>        NameError: name 'df2' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

To use matplotlib, you need use the backend. There's a video in English by Sentdex to use the backend. Plotting images in tkinter is different.

[Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zw6M-BnAPP0&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDclKx-QpC9wntnURXVJqLyk&index=7&t=0s)

Also in the video Sentdex use

for Python3.X use

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk
```

instead of

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
```

and maybe these libraries you will requier later

```
import tkinter as tk
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
```

Example code to plot:

```
ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
#new_data contains the data. In this example code, nothing
new_data.plot(kind='barh', legend=False, ax=ax) #Type of plot

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.figure, self.frame_graficos)
canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=1, column=0)

#Toolbar for icons that matplotlib give us
toolbarFrame = tk.Frame(self.frame_graficos)
toolbarFrame.grid(row=0, column=0) # use pack if you're using pack command
toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, toolbarFrame)
```